# Grant MSO privileges based on SO reputation

Tags: feature-request, reputation, meta, privileges

I am fairly active on Stack Overflow in terms on tidying up. If I see small typos, incorrect tags, extraneous salutations and valedictions, I clean them up. As I started to pursue MSO a bit more to offer my assistance there, it's obvious that I can't just jump in and start doing certain things I've grown accustomed to on SO because I haven't unlocked certain privileges yet.

Understanding the each site's Meta area is, in fact, its own entity, with an entirely different focus, it understandably makes sense to require users to go through the paces to earn reputation to unlock these privileges again. However, at the same time, it is at pretty much the same level as its parent. I care about the SO community and MSO is a place to help better it.

So, my question is *why* is there such a gap between parent and meta? Or better yet, **is there a better way** to do it? I say yes.

### Proposal

We obviously just don't want to start handing out privileges to people on meta with very small amounts of reputation. I propose we come up with a new Meta Privilege table that uses an "either/or" way of granting privileges to those heavily invested in the parent community.

Here's the revised table I came up with to work with this idea. You would need to reach the "Parent Site Rep" **OR** the "Meta Rep" to unlock the privilege on Meta only.

```
+-----------------+----------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| Parent Site Rep | Meta Rep | Privilege                   | Explanation                                             |
+-----------------+----------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
|    100,000      |  20,000  | trusted user                | Expanded editing, deletion and undeletion privileges    |
+-----------------+----------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
|     75,000      |  15,000  | protect questions           | Mark questions as protected                             |
+-----------------+----------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
|     50,000      |  10,000  | access to moderator tools   | Handle flags, access reports, delete questions          |
+-----------------+----------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
|     20,000      |   5,000  | approve tag wiki edits      | Approve edits to tag wikis made by regular users        |
+-----------------+----------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
|     10,000      |   3,000  | cast close and reopen votes | Help decide whether posts are off-topic or duplicates   |
+-----------------+----------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
|      7,500      |   2,500  | create tag synonyms         | Decide which tags have the same meaning as others       |
+-----------------+----------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
|      5,000      |   2,000  | access review queues        | Access first posts and late answers review queues       |
+-----------------+----------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
|      5,000      |   2,000  | edit questions and answers  | Edits to any question or answer are applied immediately |
+-----------------+----------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
|      2,500      |   1,000  | create gallery chat rooms   | Create chat rooms where only specific users may talk    |
+-----------------+----------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
|      2,500      |   1,000  | established user            | You've been around for a while; see vote counts         |
+-----------------+----------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
|      2,000      |     500  | create tags                 | Add new tags to the site                                |
+-----------------+----------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
|      1,500      |     250  | view close votes            | View and cast close/reopen votes on your own questions  |
+-----------------+----------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
|      1,250      |     200  | reduce ads                  | Some ads are now automatically disabled                 |
+-----------------+----------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
|      1,000      |     125  | vote down                   | Indicate when questions and answers are not useful      |
+-----------------+----------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

For example, if you reach 50,000 reputation on the parent site **OR** you reach 10,000 reputation on the meta site, you would unlock "access to moderator tools" on the meta site.*

<sub>* Reputation numbers are just an arbitrary set of ratios I came up with while writing this with no other thoughts given and probably would need to be adjusted.</sub>

---

This proposal is obviously not perfect, but I believe there is some good starting ground for bridging the gap between parent and meta, possibly helping the moderator's already heavy loads, and allowing the community to get a little more hand-ons with itself for those who really dedicate the time to it.

Comment: I fear you wasted your time, as you can now see very soon(ish) this will become moot.

Comment: I'm not quite sure why this would be considered a duplicate of a question talking about how SO is getting it's own MSO. This has to do with reputation between MSO and SO (which would be something that would probably be perfect to include in such a case), but my question has nothing to do with creating a SO specific meta.

Comment: When MSO (this site) will become per site meta of Stack Overflow it will have no reputation of its own anymore, so what you suggest is not relevant.

Comment: @MichaelIrigoyen It has everything to do with it.  Site specific metas share rep with the parent site.  Technically it's no a dupe, but the post is essentially the announcement of the eventual change that is implementing almost this exact feature.  It's not a duplicate in the sense of asking the same question, but it *is* a duplicate in the sense that it answers your question.

Comment: @Servy I was not aware of that. I only really participate on SO/MSO. Therefore, that makes a lot of sense why I would think that. Learn something new everyday! ;)

Comment: @MichaelIrigoyen That's why I proposed the duplicate, so you could see that.  It explains that in the post.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: "very soon(ish)" doesn't mean "never". You're looking for "Real Soon Now", which does.

Comment: @Wooble this, or simply 6-8 weeks. It can happen next week and I won't be surprised one bit if it happens only during 2015.